# Best structure for inventory database

Tags: database, structure

I want to create a small database for my inventory but I have some problems on picking a structure. The inventory will be updated daily at the end of the day.

The problem I am facing is the following.

I have a table for my products, having an

```
id, name, price, quantity.
```

Now I have another table for my sales, but there is my problem. What kind of fields do I need to have. At the end of the day I want to store a record like this:

```
20       product_x       $ 5,00         $ 100,-
20       product_y       $ 5,00         $ 100,-
20       product_z       $ 5,00         $ 100,-
20       product_a       $ 5,00         $ 100,-
-------------------------------------------------
                                        $ 400,-
```

So how do I model this in a sales record. Do I just create a concatenated record with the product id's comma separated.

Or is there another way do model this the right way.

Comment: Never use a concatenated list in a field, that is an indicator that you need a related table.

Comment: What is the quantity in the product table for? Stock level?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd have a table with a row per item per day - store the date, the item ID, the quantity sold, and the price sold at (store this even though it's also in the product table - if that changes, you want the value you actually sold at preserved). You can compute totals per item-day and totals per day in queries.

Tables:

```
create table product (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(100) not null,
  price decimal(6,2) not null,
  inventory integer not null
);

create table sale (
  saledate date not null,
  product_id integer not null references product,
  quantity integer not null,
  price decimal(6,2) not null,
  primary key (saledate, product_id)
);
```

Reporting on a day:

```
select s.product_id, p.name, s.quantity, s.price, (s.quantity * s.price) as total
from product p, sale s
where p.id = s.product_id
and s.saledate = date '2010-12-5';
```

Reporting on all days:

```
select saledate, sum(quantity * price) as total
from sale
group by saledate
order by saledate;
```

A nice master report over all days, with a summary line:

```
select *
from (
    (select s.saledate, s.product_id, p.name, s.quantity, s.price, (s.quantity * s.price) as total
    from product p, sale s
    where p.id = s.product_id)
  union
    (select saledate, NULL, 'TOTAL', sum(quantity), NULL, sum(quantity * price) as total
    from sale group by saledate)
) as summedsales
order by saledate, product_id;
```

Answer (score 86):

This is a model which supports many aspects,

1. Supports Sites, Locations and Warehouses etc.
2. Supports Categorization and Grouping
3. Support Generic Product (Ex. "Table Clock" and specific product "Citizen C123 Multi Alarm Clock" )
4. Also support Brand Variants (by various manufacturers)
5. Has CSM (color / size / model support) Ex. Bata Sandles (Color 45 Inch Blue color)
6. Product Instances with serials (such as TVs , Refrigerators etc.)
7. Lot control / Batch control with serial numbers.
8. Pack Size / UOM and UOM Conversion
9. Manufacturer and Brands  as well as Suppliers
10. Also included example transaction table (Purchase order)
11. There are many other transaction types such as Issues, Transfers, Adjustments etc.

Hope this would help. Please let me know if you need further information on each table.

Cheers...!!!

Wajira Weerasinghe.

### Sites

- id
- site_code
- Site_name

### Warehouse

- id
- site_id
- warehouse_code
- warehouse_name

### Item Category

- id
- category_code
- category_name

### Item Group

- id
- group_code
- group_name

### Generic Product

- id
- generic_name

### Product

- id
- product_code
- category_id
- group_id
- brand_id
- generic_id
- model_id/part_id
- product_name
- product_description
- product_price (current rate)
- has_instances(y/n)
- has_lots (y/n)
- has_attributes
- default_uom
- pack_size
- average_cost
- single_unit_product_code (for packs)
- dimension_group (pointing to dimensions)
- lot_information
- warranty_terms (general not specific)
- is_active
- deleted

### product attribute type (color/size etc.)

- id
- attribute_name

### product_attribute

- id
- product_id
- attribute_id

### product attribute value (this product -> red)

- id
- product_attribute_id
- value

### product_instance

- id
- product_id
- instance_name (as given by manufacturer)
- serial_number
- brand_id (is this brand)
- stock_id (stock record pointing  qih, location etc.)
- lot_information (lot_id)
- warranty_terms
- product attribute value id (if applicable)

### product lot

- id
- lot_code/batch_code
- date_manufactured
- date_expiry
- product attribute value id (if applicable)

### Brand

- id
- manufacturer_id
- brand_code
- brand_name

### Brand Manufacturer

- id
- manufacturer_name

### Stock

- id
- product_id
- warehouse_id, zone_id, level_id, rack_id etc.
- quantity in hand
- product attribute value id (if applicable) [we have 4 red color items etc.]

### Product Price Records

- product_id
- from_date
- product_price

### Purchase Order Header

- id
- supplier_id
- purchase_date
- total_amount

### Purchase Order Line

- id
- po_id
- product_id
- unit_price
- quantity

### Supplier

- id
- supplier_code
- supplier_name
- supplier_type

### product_uom

- id
- uom_name

### product_uom_conversion

- id
- from_uom_id
- to_uom_id
- conversion_rule

Comment: Is it good idea to store and keep updating quantity on hand or compute it via transaction table at run time? Here we may need some provisions when the transaction table grows big. Can you suggest what should be done in this scenario?

Comment: It is always good to keep the QIH in the master table. Because when we query it should not use multiple tables and specially transaction tables involved too much. Also remember it is easy to update the QIH (quantity in hand) each transaction as they are performed in relatively slow or in longer intervals which does not affect the performance doing so.

Comment: @Wajira Weerasinghe,      Is it possible for you to add example data for each table so that guys who don't have the domain knowledge (like me) will understand the usage of each table?

Comment: @Wajira Weerasinghe how would you add to your design if the products are manufactured and made from raw components, say 10 different products can be made from raw component A but each uses a different amount. So if you sell one product from the list of 10 it dynamically affects the stock levels of all the other products you can manufacture.

Comment: Nice write up @WajiraWeerasinghe! It would be complete if you could have written about the sales related schema also. Thumbed up! :-)

Comment: Thats really nice save my days of thinking about data structure for my inventory application.

Comment: Very nice and clear design. The `product_attribute` many to many table (weak entity) can be mixed with the `product_attribute_value` table to make one with pivot field `value`, might also add another field to specify type of value, or just put it all to string.

Answer (score 2):

Inventory can get quite complex to model. First you need to understand that you need to be able to tell the value of the inventory onhand based on what you paid for it. This means you cannot rely on a product table that is updated to the current price. While you might want such a table to help you figure out what to sell it for, there are tax reasons why you need to know the actual vlaue you paid for each item in the warehouse.

So first you need the product table (you might want to make sure you have an updated date column in this, it can be handy to know if your prices seem out of date).

Then you need a table that stores the actual warehouse location of each part and the price at purchase. If the items are large enough, you need a way to individually mark each item, so that you know what was taken out. Usually people use barcodes for that. This table needs to be updated to record that the part is no longer there when you sell it. I prefer to make the record inactive and have a link to my sales data to that record, so I know exactly what I paid for and what I sold each part for.

Sales should have at least two tables. One for the general information about the sale, the customername (there should also be a customer table most of the time to get this data from), the date, where it was shipped to etc.

Then a sales detail table that includes a record for each line item in the order. Include all the data you need about the part, color, size, quantity, price. This is not denormalizing, this is storing historical data. The one thing you do not want to do is rely on the prices in the product table for anything except the inital entry to this table. You do not want to do a sales report and have the numbers come out wrong becasue the product prices changed the day before.

Do not design an inventory database without consulting with an accountant or specialist in taxes. You also should do some reading on internal controls. It is easy to steal from a company undetected that has not done their work on internal controls in the database.

Comment: Instead of copying all the details into each sale line, how about versioning product rows? Instead of updating a product (or SKU) with new details, you would create a new row (so the primary key for rows would be product ID and version number), then sales can simply refer to the version sold. That lets you have historical accuracy, without duplicating data. It should simplify analysis too.

Comment: Personally versioning is much harder to manage for this sort of thing and far more likely to be incorrect over time. It is safer to store the details at the time of the sales. ANd you may not sell a product for the price inteh table anyway (think discounts, sales events, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try modelling your sales as a transaction - with a "header", i.e. who sold to, when sold, invoice # (if applicable), etc. and "line items", i.e. 20 * product_x @ $5 = $100.  The safest approach is to avoid relying upon prices etc. from the products table - as these will presumably change over time, and instead copy much of the product information (if not all) into your line item - so even when prices, item descriptions etc. change, the transaction information remains as was at the time the transaction was made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a table with fields showing the transaction properties per customer
OR
a table with fields - date, product(foreign), quantity - this way you'll have no problem with new products

Answer (score 0):

Try multiple tables with links

```
table_products
id
name

table_product_sales
id
product_id
quantity
price_per
transaction_time AS DATETIME

SELECT table_product_sales.*, table_product.name 
FROM table_product
JOIN table_product_sales
ON table_product_sales.product_id = table_product.id
GROUP BY DATE(transaction_time)
```

Haven't tried it but will something like that work?  That allows you to keep each transactions separate so you can query things like average number sold per sale, total sold per date, total sales each day, etc.